# Simple jQuery drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, beginner, jquery-ui

I would like some comments on my code and implementation for this simple piece of jQuery.

Basically it is 2 div boxes #side1 and #side2, in a container div called #frontimage, where #side2 can be swung out by dragging from right to left along #frontimage.

My jQuery code below continuously updates the CSS transform rotateY parameters for #side2 based on a mousemove event.

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sr4zw/embedded/result/

And here is the complete code including HTML and CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sr4zw/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var yDegrees = 0, slidingLength = 372, maxRotation = -45;

    $("#frontimage").on('mousedown', function( event ) {

        var originX = event.pageX;

        $("#frontimage").on("mousemove", function( event ) {

            yDegrees = yDegrees + (((originX - event.pageX) / slidingLength) * maxRotation);
            if (yDegrees < maxRotation) {
                yDegrees = maxRotation;
            };
            if (yDegrees > 0) {
                yDegrees = 0;
                };

            originX = event.pageX;

            $("#side2").css({
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + yDegrees + 'deg)',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + yDegrees + 'deg)',
                '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + yDegrees + 'deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + yDegrees + 'deg)',
                'transform': 'rotateY(' + yDegrees + 'deg)'
            });
        });
    });


    $('html').on('mouseup', function() {

        $("#frontimage").off('mousemove');

    });
});
```

Some comments on my implementation:

`yDegrees` stores the current rotation degree.
`slidingLength` is the length (in pixels) of the mouse drag that changes `yDegrees`.

Comment: As per the FAQ, please embed the code you'd like reviewed.

Comment: Right, I've done that now.

Comment: @Malachi: Any ideas on a better title?

Comment: @Jamal, working on it.  not sure what the thing does yet. but I do see some code that looks wrong.  I am no good at figuring out Titles.....lol

Comment: The code manipulates the CSS transform properties of a div by dragging left and right on the div. I'm updating the title.

Comment: cool. I am new to Javascript/jQuery so it took me a couple of minutes to follow what was going on in the code. and I am being distracted by work...ugh.  seems like your code works well, the two if statements in the middle of the code make me a little nervous about edge cases but I imagine there is logic behind that, that I am not catching.

Comment: To my knowledge the code works as it should across all recent browsers. But since it is my first foray into JavaScript and jQuery, I would like some comments on my implementation and code in general, which I am sure is not the most elegant.

Comment: there is a lot of activity using the Javascript Tag so I am going to add it to your question,  I am just starting to dive into Javascript and I know there are more people that can better help you.

Comment: Commenting on user experience, it doesn't support touch events so I can't drag it on my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
Something else that I now noticed while I was reviewing this answer,  your if statements could be written differently, it looks like it should be an if/else statement rather than two separate if statements.

We know that if `yDegrees` is less than `maxRotation` that it is not equal to zero, nor will it be equal to zero after `yDegrees` is set to `-45`(`maxRotation`).

Here is your code

> ```
>     if (yDegrees < maxRotation) {
>         yDegrees = maxRotation;
>     };
>     if (yDegrees > 0) {
>         yDegrees = 0;
>         };
> ```

and here is what I am proposing

```
if (yDegrees < maxRotation) {
    yDegrees = maxRotation;
} else if (yDegrees > 0) {
    yDegrees = 0;
}
```

If you wanted to, you could make this a one line piece of code in your JavaScript by writing a ternary inside of a ternary like this:

```
yDegrees = yDegrees < maxRotation ? maxRotation : (yDegrees > 0 ? 0 : yDegrees);
```

I also noticed that you set `originX` again after these if statements, but don't actually change it's value anywhere since the last time that you set it, and you don't use it again after this second setting of the variable, I assume that it is dead code, you should just get rid of that extra variable set.

---

From one Beginner to another,

the code looks good to me,

1. The formatting is clean
2. The code flows well and it isn't extremely hard to follow the code.

Answer (score 6):

The semicolons after the closing braces are really unnecessary, and the indentation is a bit off here:

> ```
>         if (yDegrees < maxRotation) {
>             yDegrees = maxRotation;
>         };
>         if (yDegrees > 0) {
>             yDegrees = 0;
>             };
> ```

It would be better this way:

```
        if (yDegrees < maxRotation) {
            yDegrees = maxRotation;
        }
        if (yDegrees > 0) {
            yDegrees = 0;
        }
```

This could be written more compactly:

> ```
> yDegrees = yDegrees + (((originX - event.pageX) / slidingLength) * maxRotation);
> ```

Like this:

```
yDegrees += (originX - event.pageX) / slidingLength * maxRotation;
```

That is, using `+=` and removing unnecessary parentheses.